# Javascript API for IOS Iphone 3G for camera access

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, camera

Is there a way to access the iPhone 3G camera via JavaScript to capture a photo and then utilize this photo in an HTML POST?  I came across an API called PhoneGap but from a search on here it only mentioned for the IPhone 4.  I was hoping to find something that would work on the 3G and 3GS models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is an old question, I wanted to add that this feature is coming to The Web and is already [implemented in some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia).

```
navigator.getMedia = (
    navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

There is a [W3C Specification for getUserMedia](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html).

Although this actually gets you video, you can then [take a still image from that video stream](https://gist.github.com/anantn/1852070).

There are lots of APIs coming to the browser - so good times ahead!

Answer (score 3):

Phonegap is an easy solution, and it support camera access for all iPhones.

Supported features: http://www.phonegap.com/features

Comment: From a cursory glance at phonegap it looks like you write the code in javascript, phonegap then compiles it to a native iOS app. This would mean that you can't access the camera from a purely web based app, only from an app that has been installed on the phone. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: PhoneGap embeds your web resources in a binary and gives you access to some native APIs through JavaScript. You can't access the camera from a web app. That is one of the reasons solutions like PhoneGap is so popular. However the, currently draft, Media Capture API might rectify that whenever it gets any browser implementations: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we wrote one last year. Try our git repo for iOS Web Camera — https://github.com/egghaus/iOSWebCamera

It posts through a sinatra app.

Answer (score 1):

> I came across an API called PhoneGap but from a search on here it only mentioned for the IPhone 4. I was hoping to find something that would work on the 3G and 3GS models.

PhoneGap does indeed work on 3G and 3GS.

Answer (score 1):

Now, with IO6 you can use the input file type :

```
<input type=”file”>
```

directly in your form.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to access camera via JavaScript. You should use the UIWebView delegate to handle user interaction and then call the UIImagePickerController in it's callbacks